# Why MathJax is blocked on this forum, but not on math.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Why MathJax is blocked on this forum, but not on math.stackexchange.com ? I tried $,$$, and no way i can't do latex formulae.

Thank you.

Comment: Because we're interested in TeX code and *real* output, rather than the approximate and limited rendering made by MathJax.

Comment: @egreg, With such reasoning, today people are moving towards WYSIWYG products. I understand that the rendering is bad but to interest and attract the university community, the students, it seems necessary to me. One solution would be to implement a cgi or engine with a md5 for the formulas to implement the rendering like mimetex. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Sorry, but it makes no sense: the site is about using TeX and friends in documents, not in rendering math formulas on web pages.

Comment: @greg, is it a joke ? How do you show the rendering ? By putting a jpeg, or a png in the forum ?

Comment: Besides all, this not a Forum site ... it's a question and answer site

Comment: We want to see the TeX-output and not the mathjax output, nor the output of word, nor the output of libreoffice, nor the output of some other math rendering application. So yes, we use normally screenshots.